# Handling server and api errors with promises architecture

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

Disclaimer: This isn't about solving a bug but an architecture related question

I’m setting up an API for a React/Redux app. It uses fetch and looks like so in pseudocode format

```
//API

function get(url){

    //..fetch code
    if(!response.ok){
        throw new Error("Server error");
    }

    //..looking into the received json data
    if(data["api_error"]){
        throw new Error("API Error");
    }

}

//CALLING CODE

API.get()
.then( (res) => {
    //data here is fine
})
.catch( (err) => {
   //any error caught here
})
```

**The 'issue':**

All errors will be handled in the catch. That's just because I decided to throw the API error as an Error and not pass the data along as a resolved promise with some data.

I'm not sure this is a good approach. The reason is that I'd like the `API Error` to carry some extra information with it like some data explaining what went wrong with the API so that I can pop up a window to the user. Can Error carry more data with it meaning, does it make sense to simply attach some extra data to the Error instance object or is that too hacky?

Another approach would be to resolve the API Errors instead of throwing them as if all went well and pass a custom object down the chain with a property of hasError. I don't like this approach but it's not wrong, it's just a different way to go about it.

How would you approach this?

Comment: Attaching `.details` or so to an `Error` instance is a standard practice.

Comment: Actually this problem is not specific to promises. It's the same in synchronous functions that throw exceptions.

Comment: Sure, i guess i was just trying to make it more specific in the title so that people that dont know much about promises wont waste their time (as they might have trouble reading the code in thefirst place )